# Ebay FindItemsAdvanced call including GetHistograms

Tags: php, xml, sdk, ebay-api

[Finditemsadvanced](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/finditemsadvanced.html) call in Ebay webservices and in the [SDK for PHP](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php) includes the possibility to getHistograms for categories.

[FindingServices.php](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php/blob/master/src/DTS/eBaySDK/Finding/Services/FindingService.php) display the following code:

```
public function getHistograms(\DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\GetHistogramsRequest $request)
{
    return $this->callOperation(
        'getHistograms',
        $request,
        '\DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\GetHistogramsResponse'
    );
}

public function findItemsAdvanced(\DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\FindItemsAdvancedRequest $request)
{
    return $this->callOperation(
        'findItemsAdvanced',
        $request,
        '\DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\FindItemsAdvancedResponse'
    );
}
```

In my controller I try two version to call FindingItemsAdvanced including GetHistograms.

```
/** Create the service object.*/
$service = new DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Services\FindingService(array(
    'appId' => $config['production']['appId'],
    'apiVersion' => $config['findingApiVersion'],
    'globalId' => DTS\eBaySDK\Constants\GlobalIds::US
));

/** Create the request object.*/
$request = new DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\FindItemsAdvancedRequest();
$request->keywords = 'ipod nano';
$request->categoryId = array('73839');/** Search across two categories. * DVDs & Movies > DVDs & Blue-ray (617) * Books > Fiction & Literature (171228)*/

$request->outputSelector = array('AspectHistogram','CategoryHistogram','SellerInfo');

$itemFilter = new DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\ItemFilter();/** Filter results to only include auction items or auctions with buy it now. */
$itemFilter->name = 'ListingType';
$itemFilter->value[] = 'FixedPrice';
$itemFilter->value[] = 'AuctionWithBIN';
$request->itemFilter[] = $itemFilter;

/** Get Histograms */
check below option 1 and option 2 and its errors

/** response */
$response = $service->findItemsAdvanced($request);
```

using option 1:

```
$request->getHistograms = new DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\GetHistogramsRequest();
$request->getHistograms = (array('73839'));
```

but its giving me the following error: `Unknown property: DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\FindItemsAdvancedRequest::getHistograms`

using option 2:

```
$request1 = new DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\GetHistogramsRequest();
$histograms = $service->getHistograms($request1);
$request->$histograms = (array('73839'));
```

but its giving me the following error: `"Unknown property: DTS\eBaySDK\Finding\Types\FindItemsAdvancedRequest::Object"`

I know that in the SDK getHistograms() is not part of FindItemsAdvanced() but its a part of FindingService.php consequently I assume it could be called in the same action. Any help or example code using finditems with histograms in same call appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The category that you are using is Consumer Electronics > Portable Audio & Headphones > iPods & MP3 Players (73839). While this is a valid category ID, both getHistograms and findItemsAdvanced will not return a categoryHistogram element. The reason for this is explained in the documentation for [getHistograms](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/getHistograms.html#Response.categoryHistogramContainer)

> This container is returned only when the specified category has
>   children categories.

And also in the [findItemsAdvanced](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html#Response.categoryHistogramContainer) documentation.

> The category IDs returned for items in search results are for the leaf
>   categories in which the items are listed. If you use these category
>   IDs as input, the response will not return a category histogram.

In other words the categoryHistogram element will not be returned by either service if a leaf category is specified in the request. A leaf category is just a category that has no children. Since the category 73839 is a leaf category you will instead have to use its parent Consumer Electronics > Portable Audio & Headphones (15052).

The links below should return the categoryHistogram. You just need to replace `<YOUR APP ID>` in the URL.

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=<YOUR APP ID>&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&categoryId(0)=15052&outputSelector(0)=AspectHistogram&outputSelector(1)=CategoryHistogram&outputSelector(2)=SellerInfo

http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=<YOUR APP ID>&OPERATION-NAME=getHistograms&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&categoryId(0)=15052
```

Comment: thank you David, its clear with your explanation. best regards!